# Sentencia IF dentro de SQL para consulta PDO

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas, Ordenes y Trabajadores. La Orden se crea y se asocia, o no, un trabajador. Cuando hago la consulta SQL que describo, si el trabajador es 0 la consulta es nula.

Mi consulta es la siguiente: se puede realizar un if o un case, para que si orden.trabajador=0 entonces me devuelva el valor en nombre="NO ASIGNADO"?

```
SELECT *FROM orden INNER JOIN trabajadores
                            WHERE orden.responsable=trabajadores.id_trabajador
                            ORDER BY fecha asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así sería mas o menos lo que pides, saludos.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN orden.trabajador = 0 THEN 'NO ASIGNADO' ELSE 'ASIGNADO' END ASIGNADO 
FROM orden INNER JOIN trabajadores 
WHERE orden.responsable=trabajadores.id_trabajador
ORDER BY fecha asc
```